# What's the frequency response of air, with respect to sound propagation?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

It's a very simple question but I could not find an answer anywhere on the internet.

I'm interested not only on the air magnitude response, but especially on the phase response. Is it a linear phase system? If it's not, how bad is the phase distortion with frequency?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sound+absorption+air+dispersion&oq=sound+absorption+air+dispersion&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6014.12280.0.13943.15.15.0.0.0.0.116.1310.12j3.15.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.14.1232...0j0i67k1j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i21k1j33i160k1.KYKVS97KHhM

Comment: Interesting question. It appears that air is a fairly non-dispersive medium, which means that there shouldn't be much phase distortion: "In a non-dispersive medium, the speed of sound is independent of sound frequency, so the speeds of energy transport and sound propagation are the same for all frequencies. Air, a mixture of oxygen and nitrogen, constitutes a non-dispersive medium. However, air does contain a small amount of CO2 which is a dispersive medium, and causes dispersion to air at ultrasonic frequencies (> 28 kHz).[6]" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound )

Comment: I might have missed the "air dispersion" keyword when searching. Thank you both for the inputs

Comment: Search on atmospheric attenuation.  There are some pretty famous, well known formulae for calculation the response for water and air.  Of course this may be only part of what you are looking for.  Non-attenuating phase shifts are another.  But reading one topic will likely reveal sources for the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Dissipation of energy

There are 3 types of losses that occur when sound waves propagate through a gas.  These losses are caused by

1. viscosity
2. heat conduction
3. molecular exchange

Each process is characterized by a phenomenological *relaxation time* $\tau$, with modified wave equation

\begin{equation}
\left( 1 + \tau \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right) 
\nabla^2 p = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2} \; .
\end{equation}

### Lossy Helmholtz equation

When the time-dependence is harmonic ($e^{i\omega t}$), this equation becomes the so-called lossy Helmholtz equation

\begin{equation}
\left( \nabla^2 + \cal{K}^2 \right) p = 0 \; ,
\end{equation} 
where $\cal{K}$ is a complex wavenumber:

$$\cal{K} = \frac{\omega}{c} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+i\omega\tau}} = k(\omega) - i \alpha(\omega) \; .$$
The implications are that

- The $\omega$ dependence of $k$ means that the propagation is **dispersive**.
- The existence of a finite $\alpha$ means that the wave **decays** like $e^{-\alpha x}$ as it propagates.

### Results for typical gases

The value of $\alpha/f^2$ is approximately constant for typical gases, and depends on the type of gas (it is about 0.5 for Helium and 2.0 for Oxygen). For monatomic gases like Argon and Helium, the losses are dominated by (1) and (2) (so-called classical losses).  Classical losses are not adequate to accurately describe polyatomic gases, like Oxygen.

### Frequency response

The original equation asks for the frequency response, although this is not normally the way to characterize dissipation.  However, based on the previous result, one observes that at a distance of 1m, the decrease in sound pressure level (SPL) is

$$ p = p_0 e^{-\alpha - i k} $$

When $\omega \tau \ll 1$, we can write

$$\alpha = \frac{\omega^2 \tau}{2c} \; .$$

Thus, a measure of the **frequency response** is

$$ \frac{p}{p_0} = e^{-\omega^2 \tau/c} \; , $$

where I have dropped an uninteresting phase factor.